# How to get emacs to highlight and link file paths

Tags: unix, emacs, elisp

Is there some emacs lisp code that would automatically find /nfs file paths in the buffer and highlight/link to them? So clicking on them would open that file?

Example path:
/nfs/foo/bar/file.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's probably a package that does this already, but I don't know of it.

This bit of code adds buttons to text it thinks looks like a path to a file.  You can add the function `'buttonize-buffer` to `find-file-hooks` or run it manually (or conditionally).

```
(define-button-type 'find-file-button
  'follow-link t
  'action #'find-file-button)

(defun find-file-button (button)
  (find-file (buffer-substring (button-start button) (button-end button))))

(defun buttonize-buffer ()
  "turn all file paths into buttons"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "/[^ \t]*" nil t)
      (make-button (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) :type 'find-file-button))))

; (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'buttonize-buffer)   ; uncomment to add to find file
```

Comment: This is perfect. I did some more characters to avoid... re-search-forward "/nfs[^ \t\n,\'\"]*" .. there's probably more that I will find, but it's easy enough to add.

Answer (score 5):

Try the built-in package ffap (find file at point):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileAtPoint

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/FFAP.html

I don't use the minor mode, instead binding a key to `ffap` that I hit when on a filename.

Comment: this might work too, but has the extra step of moving the pointer to the place of the path and hitting a key. Trey's answer is mouse driven and very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Great solution.  I agree in using `ffap`, which is part of GNU Emacs. `ffap`
solves many subtle problems, it expands environment variables and also catches URLs.

However, `ffap` cannot be used easily from own Lisp. My reimplementation of `buttonize-buffer` is based on `ffap-next-regexp` and `ffap-guesser`. The hard part was to work arround the bug mentioned below, and to get the start point of the file or URL, which `ffap-guesser` does not provide.

The parser scans through the current buffer and prints details into the message buffer; there you can see which strings are guessed to be files, which match, and which are buttonized.

```lisp
    (defun buttonize-buffer ()
      "Turn all file paths and URLs into buttons."
      (interactive)
      (require 'ffap)
      (deactivate-mark)
      (let (token guess beg end reached bound len)
        (save-excursion
          (setq reached (point-min))
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (re-search-forward ffap-next-regexp nil t)
            ;; There seems to be a bug in ffap, Emacs 23.3.1: `ffap-file-at-point'
            ;; enters endless loop when the string at point is "//".
            (setq token (ffap-string-at-point))
            (unless (string= "//" (substring token 0 2))
              ;; Note that `ffap-next-regexp' only finds some "indicator string" for a
              ;; file or URL. `ffap-string-at-point' blows this up into a token.
              (save-excursion
                (beginning-of-line)
                (when (search-forward token (point-at-eol) t)
                  (setq beg (match-beginning 0)
                        end (match-end 0)
                        reached end))
                )
              (message "Found token %s at (%d-%d)" token beg (- end 1))
              ;; Now let `ffap-guesser' identify the actual file path or URL at
              ;; point.
              (when (setq guess (ffap-guesser))
                (message "  Guessing %s" guess)
                (save-excursion
                  (beginning-of-line)
                  (when (search-forward guess (point-at-eol) t)
                    (setq len (length guess) end (point) beg (- end len))
                    ;; Finally we found something worth buttonizing. It shall have
                    ;; at least 2 chars, however.
                    (message "    Matched at (%d-%d]" beg (- end 1))
                    (unless (or (< (length guess) 2))
                      (message "      Buttonize!")
                      (make-button beg end :type 'find-file-button))
                    )))
              ;; Continue one character after the guess, or the original token.
              (goto-char (max reached end))
              (message "Continuing at %d" (point))
              )))))
```

To permanently install the function:

```lisp
    (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'buttonize-buffer)
```

A nicer solution is to be lazy:

```lisp
    (defun buttonize-current-buffer-on-idle (&optional secs)
      "Idle-timer (see \\[run-with-idle-timer]) that buttonizes filenames and URLs.
    SECS defaults to 60 seconds idle time."
      (interactive)
      (run-with-idle-timer (or secs 60) t 'buttonize-buffer))
    
    (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'buttonize-current-buffer-on-idle)
```

Comment: Nice. One just has to clean the `message` in order to make it work in the `*Messages*` buffer. Also `ffap-guesser` will strip line-number from the filename. Setting `(when (setq guess token)` instead will keep it.